# No Komodo preview available for html file with php extension

Tags: php, html, komodo

I just started using the Komodo html editor.  I want to make html pages with a .php extension so I can use php include on the pages.  But, when I do so, I lose the ability to preview the file in Komodo.  When I try to view it in a browser, the html gets outputted as text.

I am using a Mac.  Perhaps I need to download php?  I am using Mountain Lion.  I have read that the php library is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the `PHP` files on a `PHP server` for testing. `Komodo` is a text editor only. Since you're editing the text and previewing in your browser your browser can't parse the `PHP`. Since it doesn't have the `.html` extension the browser assumes it's text. Your Mac comes with Web Server capability already.

Here's a link to an entry about [installing and configuring PHP in Mountain Lion](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion).